# The vector space of absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with a special norm, then the space is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, absolute-continuity

The vector space of absolutely continuous functions $V$ on $[0,1]$ endowed with a special norm $||\cdot ||$ as $||f||=\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt +\int_0^1 |f'(t)dt|=||f||_1+||f'||_1, \quad f\in V$.   Then the space is complete.

Here is what I tried: we want to prove $V$ is complete, so it suffices to prove that $V$ is summable, i.e for any $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ||f_n||<\infty$, we can get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges in $V$.

Define $F:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n, f:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n$,  then $||F||_1\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||f_n||_1<\infty$ so that  $f\in L^1[0,1]$ and $||f||_1\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty ||f'_n||_1<\infty$ so that  $f\in L^1[0,1]$.

$\int_0^x f'=\int_0^x\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x f'_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f_n(x)-f_n(0))=F(x)-F(0)$. So $F$ is absolutely continuous, i.e $F\in V$, we get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges to $F$ in $V$.

Is this process right? or there are other correct proof?

Comment: I think that is incorrect; because in the definition of $F$ why the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n$ is convergent (if it is convergent what did you showing).

Comment: @Hamou. Because $f_n$ is fast $L^1$ convergent, so $\sum f_n$ converges a. e.

Comment: Is it possible to show directly using the definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

Another way to use the completeness of $L^1$ is to set up an isomorphism between your space (usually denoted $AC$ or $W^{1,1}$) and $L^1\oplus \mathbb R$. Such an isomorphism is given by 
$$f\mapsto \left(f',\int_0^1 f\right)$$
This map is   bounded and surjective. It also has trivial kernel. Being lazy, I'd just invoke open mapping theorem to get this over with.

Comment: How can you use open mapping theorem theorem here? We don't know if the space AC is Banach yet.